# Sabre CreatePassengerNameRecord - USE 3 ENTRY TO INPUT FACTS, TTY REQ PEND

Tags: sabre

When using the CreatePassengerNameRecord service, I encountered the following warnings. Apart from the warnings, the request appears to be successful. Is it OK to ignore these warning?

```
"Warning": [
  {
    "type": "BusinessLogic",
    "timeStamp": "2019-09-13T07:01:39.560-05:00",
    "SystemSpecificResults": [
      {
        "Message": [
          {
            "code": "WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE",
            "content": "USE 3 ENTRY TO INPUT FACTS"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "BusinessLogic",
    "timeStamp": "2019-09-13T07:01:39.796-05:00",
    "SystemSpecificResults": [
      {
        "Message": [
          {
            "code": "WARN.SWS.HOST.WARNING_RESPONSE",
            "content": "EndTransactionLLSRQ: TTY REQ PEND"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Request:

```
{
  "CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ": {
    "version": "2.2.0",
    "haltOnAirPriceError": true,
    "TravelItineraryAddInfo": {
      "AgencyInfo": {
        "Ticketing": {
          "TicketType": "7TAW",
          "TicketTimeLimit": "09-13T21:00"
        }
      },
      "CustomerInfo": {
        "ContactNumbers": {
          "ContactNumber": [
            {
              "NameNumber": "1.1",
              "Phone": "12345678",
              "PhoneUseType": "H"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Email": [
          {
            "NameNumber": "1.1",
            "Address": "email@example.com"
          }
        ],
        "PersonName": [
          {
            "NameNumber": "1.1",
            "PassengerType": "ADT",
            "GivenName": "Adult",
            "Surname": "Doe"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "AirBook": {
      "HaltOnStatus": [
        {
          "Code": "HL"
        },
        {
          "Code": "KK"
        },
        {
          "Code": "LL"
        },
        {
          "Code": "NN"
        },
        {
          "Code": "NO"
        },
        {
          "Code": "UC"
        },
        {
          "Code": "US"
        }
      ],
      "OriginDestinationInformation": {
        "FlightSegment": [
          {
            "ArrivalDateTime": "2019-11-11T18:05:00",
            "DepartureDateTime": "2019-11-12T17:00:00",
            "FlightNumber": "808",
            "NumberInParty": "1",
            "ResBookDesigCode": "T",
            "Status": "NN",
            "MarriageGrp": "O",
            "DestinationLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "KUL"
            },
            "MarketingAirline": {
              "Code": "OD",
              "FlightNumber": "808"
            },
            "OriginLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "SIN"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "RedisplayReservation": {
        "NumAttempts": 10,
        "WaitInterval": 300
      }
    },
    "AirPrice": [
      {
        "PriceComparison": {
          "AcceptablePriceIncrease": {
            "Amount": 0.1,
            "HaltOnNonAcceptablePrice": true
          },
          "AmountSpecified": 1460
        },
        "PriceRequestInformation": {
          "Retain": true,
          "OptionalQualifiers": {
            "PricingQualifiers": {
              "PassengerType": [
                {
                  "Code": "ADT",
                  "Quantity": "1"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "SpecialReqDetails": {
      "SpecialService": {
        "SpecialServiceInfo": {
          "AdvancePassenger": [
            {
              "Document": {
                "IssueCountry": "SG",
                "NationalityCountry": "SG",
                "ExpirationDate": "2025-12-12",
                "Number": "S1234567G",
                "Type": "P"
              },
              "PersonName": {
                "GivenName": "Adult",
                "Surname": "Doe",
                "DateOfBirth": "1990-11-11",
                "Gender": "M",
                "NameNumber": "1.1"
              }
            }
          ],
          "SecureFlight": [
            {
              "SegmentNumber": "A",
              "PersonName": {
                "DateOfBirth": "1990-11-11",
                "NameNumber": "1.1",
                "GivenName": "Adult",
                "Surname": "Doe",
                "Gender": "M"
              },
              "VendorPrefs": {
                "Airline": {
                  "Hosted": true
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "Service": []
        }
      }
    },
    "PostProcessing": {
      "EndTransaction": {
        "Source": {
          "ReceivedFrom": "SWS_CLIENT"
        }
      },
      "RedisplayReservation": {
        "waitInterval": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason, stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to post this and insists that "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." For this reason, I am padding the post with this text as I am not able to add any further details with regards to this question.

Comment: Have you inquired with sabre web services support?

Comment: Their support portal claims that "Sabre® engineers engage with our developers on StackOverflow" and encourages developers to post here

Comment: If you have an account with Sabre you can email webservices.support@sabre.com, include your PCC in the subject line. Be descriptive and detailed in your inquiry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This used to be needed for older service versions, where you had to specify if the itinerary contained hosted (AA for TN customers) or non-hosted carriers (any carrier other than AA for TN customers). This was because the service was sending the 4 and 3 formats, and depending on your itinerary you had to use one or the other (for any SSR and OSI messages like INF, DOCS, etc.). After PassengerDetailsRQ 3.3.0, and CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ 2.2.0 is using PassengerDetails 3.4.0, this is automatic now, so you can remove:

> SpecialReqDetails/SpecialServiceRQ/SpecialServiceInfo/AdvancePasseng
>   er/VendorPrefs
>   SpecialReqDetails/SpecialServiceRQ/SpecialServiceInfo/SecureFlight/Ven
>   dorPrefs
>   SpecialReqDetails/SpecialServiceRQ/SpecialServiceInfo/Service/VendorPr
>   efs/Airline/@Hosted

Answer (score 0):

change value of  ***"Hosted": true*** to ***false*** inside *VendorPrefs>"Airline"*.
And **EndTransactionLLSRQ: TTY REQ PEND** is the general response from system to indicate that other service requested are yet to be confirmed by airlines. This is not the error.